# SSJS for resource href in themes

Tags: themes, xpages

We have multiple applications sharing single css for themes. So we want to move this common CSS and resources into common database, and refer them in themes dynamically.

I can refer these css using following hardcoded path :

```
<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>/.ibmxspres/domino/common/designstore.nsf/custom_layout.css</href>
</resource>
```

This way it is working fine. But we want to fetch the database path from configuration. So that '/common/designstore.nsf' path don't have to be hard coded in themes.

I tried putting designstore db path in sessionScope variable beforeRenderResponse of a Xpage. And referred scope var in themes.

```
<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>#{sessionScope.commonCSSPath}</href>
</resource>
```

Where sessionScope.commonCSSPath = "/.ibmxspres/domino/common/designstore.nsf/custom_layout.css"

Please let me know if we can compute the db path in resources, or any other way to refer CSS files from other databases using computed path.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know you can not use any dynamic code for resource attributes in themes. You can only use hardcoded static text, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the `href` value using Javascript instead of EL:

```
<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>#{javascript:sessionScope.commonCSSPath}</href>
</resource>
```

I am not sure if the timing of beforeRenderResponse and when a theme kicks in, makes it possible to reference a sessionScope variable. Let us know how it goes.

--

**Update:**

I use the following in a theme to determine the rendered property of a field and it works:

```
<control>
    ...
    <property>
        <name>rendered</name>
        <value>#{javascript:document.isEditable()}</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```

I also use a function to determine the value property where the function is a SSJS function that looks up a value in a profile document:

```
<control>
    ...
    <property>
        <name>value</name>
        <value>#{javascript:getNecessaryValue("SetupProfile", "fieldWithValue")}</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```

Hopefully this can inspire you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Javascript is also not working. I tried putting sessionScope variable in all 5 events of xpage, still not working. Any other way? Is it possible to use datacontext in themes? something like data source?

Comment: I have added an example of using document.isEditable() and of using a function in a theme. Maybe this can inspire you to do what you want?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. Yes for Controls it is working fine, <value> tags I can use SSJS or EL to get the dynamic values. But for Resources it is not working. I am not sure how to pass dynamic values to <href> tag. It is not taking SSJS/EL...